# Kotlin lazy usage

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm currently using Realm in my application, and to make sure i manage Realm instances correctly, i introduced in my base Activity a variable like this:

```
protected val realm: Realm by lazy {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
}
```

And then in onDestroy i do this:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    realm.close()
}
```

And then i realised this is a waste. If the current activity doesn't use realm, it will open and immediately close in `onDestroy`.

So i updated to this:

```
    private var usedRealm = false

    protected val realm: Realm by lazy {
        usedRealm = true
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        if (usedRealm) {
            realm.close()
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to accomplish the same, without the extra flag?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. There is a bug in your current implementation. If `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` throws then `usedRealm` will be set to `true` but the lazy won't actually be initialized (intialization would have failed). You can fix this by only calling `usedRealm = true` *after* calling `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`:

   ```
   protected val realm: Realm by lazy {
       val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
       usedRealm = true
       realm
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   protected val realm: Realm by lazy {
       Realm.getDefaultInstance().apply { usedRealm = true }
   }
   ```
2. You can accomplish the same without the extra flag by keeping a reference to the raw [`Lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/) object itself:

   ```
   private val lazyRealm = lazy { Realm.getDefaultInstance() }

   protected val realm by lazyRealm

   override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()

       if (lazyRealm.isInitialized()) {
           realm.close()
       }
   }
   ```

   This still requires an additional field but you no longer have to maintain the initialization state yourself.
3. You can also use `Lazy` directly instead of [as a delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy):

   ```
   protected val lazyRealm = lazy { Realm.getDefaultInstance() }

   override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()

       if (lazyRealm.isInitialized()) {
           lazyRealm.value.close()
       }
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   protected val lazyRealm = lazy { Realm.getDefaultInstance() }

   override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()

       with(lazyRealm) {
           if (isInitialized()) {
               value.close()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This makes it so that there is no extra property but `Lazy` is now part of your API and everywhere where you would have simply referenced `realm` you now have to reference `lazyRealm.value`. You get to weigh the pros and cons. :-)