# Kotlin: Check if lazy val has been initialised

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to tell if a lazy val has been initialised in Kotlin without initialising it in the process?

eg if I have a lazy val, querying if it is null would instantiate it

```
val messageBroker: MessageBroker by lazy { MessageBroker() }
if (messageBroker == null) {
    // oops
}
```

I could potentially use a second variable, but that seems messy.

```
private var isMessageBrokerInstantiated: Boolean = false
val messageBroker: MessageBroker by lazy {
    isMessageBrokerInstantiated = true
    MessageBroker()
}

...

if (!isMessageBrokerInstantiated) {
    // use case
}
```

Is there some sexy way of determining this, like `if (Lazy(messageBroker).isInstantiated())`?

Related (but not the same): [How to check if a "lateinit" variable has been initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There is a way, but you have to access the delegate object which is returned by `lazy {}`:

```
val messageBrokerDelegate = lazy { MessageBroker() }
val messageBroker by messageBrokerDelegate

if(messageBrokerDelegate.isInitialized())
    ...
```

`isInitialized` is a public method on interface `Lazy<T>`, here are the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/).

Comment: Note that you can also use a `Lazy` directly instead of as a delegate and access the lazily evaluated value with [`Lazy.value`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/value.html). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/38794502/3255152.

Answer (score 36):

Since Kotlin 1.1, you can access a property delegate directly using [`.getDelegate()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property0/get-delegate.html).

You can write an extension property for a property reference that checks that it has a `Lazy` delegate that has already been initialized:

```
/**
 * Returns true if a lazy property reference has been initialized, or if the property is not lazy.
 */
val KProperty0<*>.isLazyInitialized: Boolean
    get() {
        if (this !is Lazy<*>) return true

        // Prevent IllegalAccessException from JVM access check on private properties.
        val originalAccessLevel = isAccessible
        isAccessible = true
        val isLazyInitialized = (getDelegate() as Lazy<*>).isInitialized()
        // Reset access level.
        isAccessible = originalAccessLevel
        return isLazyInitialized
    }
```

Then at the use site:

```
val messageBroker: MessageBroker by lazy { MessageBroker() }

if (this::messageBroker.isLazyInitialized) {
    // ... do stuff here
}
```

<sup>This solution requires `kotlin-reflect` to be on the classpath. With Gradle, use 
`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`</sup>

<sup>The `isAccessible = true` part is required for the `.getDelegate()`, because otherwise it cannot access the private field storing the delegate reference.</sup>

Comment: Wow, I did't see it in the release notes!

Comment: Make sure you import isAccessible: import kotlin.reflect.jvm.isAccessible

Comment: I had to remove "if (this !is Lazy<*>) return true", without that it works. Changes in 1.3?

Comment: If you're using R8 (perhaps ProGuard too, not tested), two things need to be excluded from minification: the class that contains the field must be accessible, along with its parent class and implemented interfaces. And the field itself must be marked `@delegate:Keep`.

Comment: @Neikius Same here.

Comment: This answer didn't fit me, because for some reason the value gets initialized, when I use 'isLazyInitialized'

Answer (score 19):

Testing if the lazy property is easy enough:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty0
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.isAccessible

val KProperty0<*>.isLazyInitialized: Boolean
    get() {
        // Prevent IllegalAccessException from JVM access check
        isAccessible = true
        return (getDelegate() as Lazy<*>).isInitialized()
    }
```

…but you can make it even easier to reference a property without initializing it:

```
/**
 * Returns the value of the given lazy property if initialized, null
 * otherwise.
 */
val <T> KProperty0<T>.orNull: T?
    get() = if (isLazyInitialized) get() else null
```

Now you can do things like:

```
private val myList by lazy {
    mutableSetOf<String>()
}

fun add(str: String) {
    // Create the list if necessary
    myList += str
}

fun remove(str: String) {
    // Don't create the list
    ::myList.orNull?.remove(str)
}

fun clear() {
    // Don't create the list
    ::myList.orNull?.clear()
}
```

Comment: Needed Gradle depencency `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"` for `kotlin.reflect.jvm.isAccessible`.