# Lazy initialized objects are always created

Tags: android, kotlin

In some case my broadcast receiver is not required and so need to check if the receiver is null or not but somehow this object is not null even if not using it and causing crash.

> ```
> private val myBroadCastReceiver by lazy {
>    MyBroadcastReceiver()
> }
> if(myBroadCastReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(myBroadCastReceiver)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you are trying null check, its initialised and thus it not null. Try this this instead of lazy.

```
private var myBroadCastReceiver : MyBroadcastReceiver? = null
```

or try this answer
[Kotlin: Check if lazy val has been initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522739/kotlin-check-if-lazy-val-has-been-initialised)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit\You can go through this to know which is appropriate to use lateinit or lazy initialisation

Comment: This needs to be a var though

Comment: i changed val to var

Answer (score 4):

Because you declare `myBroadcastReceiver` as Lazy, that means that you won't use it until you call `MyBroadcastReceiver()`. Which you do in your `if` statement.

So if you check it that way, it won't be null, because you actually execute `MyBroadcastReceiver()` here `if(myBroadCastReceiver...)`